# Show that $|T^n(z)| → 1$ as $n → ∞$ for all $z ∈ \Bbb D$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $T$ be a Moebius transformation mapping the unit disk $\Bbb D$ onto itself such that $T$ has no fixed points
in $\Bbb D$. Show that $|T^n(z)| → 1$ as $n → ∞$ for all $z ∈ \Bbb D$.[$T^n=T \circ T\circ \cdots \circ T$(n times)]

I know that if it fixes $0$ then $T(z)= \lambda z$ where $|\lambda|=1$.

Again $Aut(\Bbb D)=\{z \mapsto \lambda \phi_a(z) : |\lambda|=1, a \in \Bbb D \}$ where $\phi_a(z)=\frac {z-a} {1- \bar a z}$.

Now how to calculate. Again please tell me how to classify $Aut(\Bbb D)$ upto conjugacy.

Answer (score 1):

- An automorphism of $\mathbb{D}$ with no fixed points in $\mathbb{D}$ has either one or two fixed points on the unit circle $\partial\mathbb{D}$.

The automorphisms of $\mathbb{D}$ are Möbius transformations, thus they are also automorphisms of the Riemann sphere $\widehat{\mathbb{C}}$. Since $z \mapsto \overline{T(1/\overline{z})}$ is holomorphic and $T(z)\cdot \overline{T(1/\overline{z})} = T(z)\cdot \overline{T(z)} \equiv 1$ on the unit circle, the identity theorem tells us that $T(1/\overline{z}) = 1/\overline{T(z)}$ for all $z \in \widehat{\mathbb{C}}$ (using the usual conventions $1/0 = \infty$ and $1/\infty = 0$). Hence, if $z$ is a fixed point of $T$, so is $1/\overline{z}$, i.e. the fixed points of $T$ are symmetric with respect to the unit circle. If $T$ has no fixed point in the open unit disk, it has therefore no fixed point in the complement of the closed unit disk, so all of $T$'s fixed points lie on the unit circle. Every Möbius transformation other than the identity has exactly one or two fixed points in the Riemann sphere.

- The unit disk is conformally equivalent to the upper half-plane, where the situation is simpler to analyse.

The Möbius transformation $A \colon z \mapsto \frac{z-i}{z+i}$ maps the upper half-plane to the unit disk. Thus, if $T$ is an automorphism of the unit disk, then $S = A^{-1}\circ T \circ A$ is an automorphism of the upper half-plane. A point $p\in \widehat{\mathbb{C}}$ is a fixed point of $T$ if and only if $A^{-1}(p)$ is a fixed point of $S$.

- By conjugating with an appropriate automorphism of the upper half-plane, we can assume that either $\infty$ is the only fixed point, or the two fixed points are $0$ and $\infty$.

If $S$ has only one fixed point $p$, and that is not $\infty$, then $p \in \mathbb{R}$. Let $B$ the Möbius transformation mapping $p-2 \mapsto 0$, $p-1 \mapsto 1$ and $p \mapsto \infty$. Then $B$ is an automorphism of the upper half-plane and $B \circ S \circ B^{-1}$ is an automorphism of the upper half-plane with $\infty$ as its only fixed point. If $S$ has two real fixed points $p < q$, let $B$ the Möbius transformation mapping $p \mapsto 0$, $\frac{1}{2}(p+q) \mapsto 1$ and $q \mapsto \infty$. Then $B \circ S \circ B^{-1}$ is an automorphism of the upper half-plane with fixed points $0$ and $\infty$. If $S$ has two fixed points, $p \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\infty$, let $B \colon z \mapsto z - p$. Then $B \circ S \circ B^{-1}$ is an automorphism of the upper half-plane with fixed points $0$ and $\infty$.

A Möbius transformation whose only fixed point is $\infty$ is a translation $z \mapsto z + b$. Since we consider an automorphism $S$ of the upper half-plane that is not the identity, we have $b \in \mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$. Thus $S^n(z) \to \infty$ for every $z \in \widehat{\mathbb{C}}$. Going back to the automorphism $T$ of the unit disk, it follows that if $T$ has only one fixed point $p$ (on the unit circle), then $T^n(z) \to p$ for all $z\in \widehat{\mathbb{C}}$, thus in particular $\lvert T^n(z)\rvert \to 1$ for $z\in \mathbb{D}$.

If a Möbius transformation $S$ has $0$ and $\infty$ as its only fixed points, it is of the form $z \mapsto az$ for some $a \in \mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$. If $S$ is an automorphism of the upper half-plane, it follows that $a$ is real and positive. Since $S$ is not the identity, $a \in (0,1) \cup (1,+\infty)$. If $a \in (0,1)$, then $S^n(z) \to 0$ for every $z \in \mathbb{C}$, and if $a \in (1,+\infty)$ then $S^n(z) \to \infty$ for every $z \in \widehat{\mathbb{C}} \setminus \{0\}$. In either case, $S^n(z)$ converges to one of the fixed point for every $z$ except for the other fixed point. Translating that to the automorphisms of the unit disk: If $T \neq \operatorname{id}$ is an automorphism of the unit disk with two fixed points $p,q$ on the unit circle, then (up to renaming the fixed points) $T^n(z) \to p$ for every $z \in \widehat{\mathbb{C}}\setminus \{q\}$, in particular $\lvert T^n(z)\rvert \to 1$ for $z \in \mathbb{D}$.

Comment: How can I prove the first hint?

Comment: An automorphism of $\mathbb{D}$ is a Möbius transformation, hence an automorphism of the Riemann sphere. You know (or if not, can easily prove) that every Möbius transformation which is not the identity has either one or two fixed points in the sphere. If a Möbius transformation leaves a circle (or straight line) invariant, its fixed points are symmetric with respect to the circle (straight line), so if one would lie outside the circle, the other would lie inside. Since we assume none lies inside, none can lie outside, so on the circle is the only possibility.

Comment: Riemann sphere means unit sphere?

Comment: The Riemann sphere is $\widehat{\mathbb{C}} = \mathbb{C}\cup \{\infty\}$. You can model it as the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^3$, but viewing it abstractly is usually better.

Comment: Consider the automorphisms of the upper half-plane with a) $\infty$ as the only fixed point, b) $0$ and $\infty$ as the only fixed points. It's not hard to find an explicit representation for them. Then you can easily see that $S^n(z)$ converges to a certain point of $\mathbb{R}\cup\{\infty\}$ for all $z$ in the upper half-plane. Pushing that back to the unit disk gives the slightly stronger than asked for result that for an automorphism $T$ of $\mathbb{D}$ with no fixed point in $\mathbb{D}$, there is a point $e^{i\psi}$ on the unit circle with $T^n(z) \to e^{i\psi}$ for all $z\in\mathbb{D}$.

Comment: Why If a Möbius transformation leaves a circle (or straight line) invariant, its fixed points are symmetric with respect to the circle (straight line)? Daniel Fischer

Comment: It's the reflection principle. If $M$ leaves $\mathbb{R}\cup \{\infty\}$ invariant, you probably know that $M(\overline{z}) = \overline{M(z)}$ [for $\tilde{M} \colon z \mapsto \overline{M(\overline{z})}$ is holomorphic and by assumption $\tilde{M}(z) = M(z)$ for $z\in\mathbb{R}$, hence the identity theorem says $\tilde{M} \equiv M$], and the general case is the same principle, using reflection in the circle instead of conjugation. Specifically for the unit circle, the reflection is $z\mapsto 1/\overline{z}$, so $1/\overline{T(1/\overline{z})} = T(z)$ first on the unit circle, then everywhere.